# Entity Framework: Different ObjectContext object error with LINQ to Entities assignment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I keep getting the following `InvalidOperationException`:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

when trying to do the following code:

```
newCorr.ReqCode = (from req in context.ReqCodeSet
                   where req.Code.Equals(requirement.Code)
                   select req).FirstOrDefault();
```

Just before this line, I am doing the following:

```
 foreach (Requirement requirement in myInformation.Reqs)
 {
     MyHwReqCorr newCorr = new MyHwReqCorr();

     newCorr.HwItem = Dictionaries.Instance.HwIdHwRecordDictionary[requirement.Id];
```

So what I'm doing is parsing through the my `Information.Reqs` list, creating a new instance of `MyHwReqCorr`, setting the `HwItem` to an item that was stored in a dictionary earlier on, and then setting the `ReqCode` by using a LINQ to SQL command which to look in a table for a req code that matches the one I'm passing in.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Any info you need, I'd be happy to provide.

EDIT: Right before I call this foreach, I can call this (as testing to verify that I can access the db):

```
List<ReqCode> reqCodeList = (from req in context.ReqCodeSet select req).ToList();
```

And I never get any errors with that.  But when I try to set an item in that list (using the where extension method like:

```
newCorr.ReqCode = reqCodeList.Where(t=>t.Code == requirement.Code).FirstOrDefault();
```

or using a dictionary as done similar to the newCorr.HwItem, I get the main error.

EDIT2:  I have also noticed something weird happening:  When I initially run, with any setup (my original or the variable method or the method Rony posted), it works.  But any subsequent run, meaning if I stop debugging and start debugging again, it fails with that error.  Only when I kill all instances of excel (which is running in the background generating a log for viewing later on) and wait about 2-3 minutes, does it work again and then follows the same situation as before...passing the first time, failing immediate subsequent times.

EDIT3: It's definitely not Excel related as I prevented Excel from starting and I still get that error.  But I did notice that if I wait some time, and try again, it works....sometimes.

Comment: The last bit (after “EDIT”) is very unclear. What is “the where property”? If you mean the `.Where()` extension method, how do you use that to set an item in a `List<>`? Could you provide the exact line of code that produces the error?

Comment: (Also, as an aside, the `from` query in the last line is redundant: you can just write `List<ReqCode> reqCodeList = context.ReqCodeSet.ToList();` and it does exactly the same thing.)

Comment: I have updated my EDIT statement.

Comment: I am giving up on this question. It took you two edits to mention Excel and that the problem is obviously connected to your use of Excel. Very likely most of the code you posted is irrelevant and the error is due to something you didn’t mention. In particular, it clearly has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: How can the use of Excel which generates a log in the background have to do with this error?

Comment: Actually, I dont think that it may have to do with Excel, my observations are not panning out as I initially described.  Ive closed all instances of excel and waited a few minutes like I have previously done and I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you retrieving all items on the same thread/context?  Try retrieving the items on same thread.

Answer (score -1):

```
newCorr.ReqCode = (from req in context.ReqCodeSet
                   where req.Code equals requirement.Code
                   select req).FirstOrDefault();
```

OR

```
newCorr.ReqCode = context.ReqCodeSet
                        Where( r => r.Code == requirement.Code)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I have created a second EDIT with my findings